# Can I enable auto-sleep at the tty login prompt?

Tags: arch-linux, login, tty, suspend

I recently turned on my computer and accidentally left it sitting at the login prompt for hours, needlessly sucking power.
A display manager would automatically suspend in that case, but I don't want one.

So can I configure the computer to go to sleep (I guess using `systemctl suspend`) after idling a few minutes at the login prompt (and ideally also in a logged in tty)?

Comment: How do you know it's not already sleeping and waiting for input to wake it up?

Comment: because the screen is stil on ^^

Comment: Okay, the title misled me - I didn't read the second paragraph. See "man systemd-sleep.conf".

Comment: can you provide a more detailed pointer? I can't find a relevant configuration option there.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "login prompt". If you haven't already, shutdown the machine and power it down. Wait a few minuts and power it up. Then wait a while to see if it blanks the scrren. Try https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend. I use lighDM as a display manager on Debian 10 Buster and I have no problems. But I see a login console after I logout - and my screen blanks after a little while after I stop using it. Also, check your /var/log/{messages,syslog} files. And dmesg.

Comment: When you boot up a plain Linux (such as Arch) without a display manager, you see a purely text-based login prompt, and the X/Wayland session is only started after login.
And no, it does not blank so far, that's why I am asking ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, apparently there isn't that much request of non X/Wayland sleep on idle programs, but I found some:

- https://github.com/mrmekon/circadian
- http://joeyh.name/code/sleepd/
- https://github.com/mountassir/sspender

I'm currently using sleepd for my laptop and my desktop.
**systemd unit**:

```
[Unit]
Description=auto sleep on idle

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=sleepd -n -u 600 -U 600 -l 0.5 -w -a -s "systemctl suspend-then-hibernate" -b 10 -d "systemctl hibernate" -a
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

acknowledgements:

- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-suspend-after-idle-or-inactivity-period-without-desktop-environment-or-x-4175524123/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399754/suspend-home-server-on-idle-inactivity